# Eclipse 2019-06 - Won't Run without Administrator Priviliges (Win10)

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to get this comparatively newer version of Eclipse running at work. However, here's what's happening when I try running eclipse.exe without running it as Administrator. Note: Running as Administrator works beautifully, but this is not a permanent solution, because I won't be able to permanently attain Admin priviliges.

[image: Initial Error]

Now, if I use the command line argument -configuration, Eclipse will start, but when I try to access OR create an entirely new workspace, I'm getting a similar error about being able to write to a directory.

[image: Workspace Error]

I've tried numerous solutions for this problem, but nothing has worked. I hope someone out there has some suggestions.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you install it as Administrator? Does your user actually own the .eclipse folder under their home directory?

Comment: I had Administrator privileges when I unzipped the archive. I tried setting myself to the owner of the directory and all subfolders, and the behaviour didn't change.

Comment: I also tried being removed from the Admin group, restarting the machine, and then unzipping and trying to run. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up having to wipe out my local Windows profile, and I was finally able to install Eclipse. Not ideal, but it got the job done.